# How is tension act microscopically in a string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Think of a massless string that goes through two pulleys attached to a roof, also massless, and look at this scenario as if you were seeing the string in its atomic constitution, looking at the parts that make it up as if you were looking atomically from end to end. There are two blocks of the same mass suspended each at one end of the string, and let's assume that the atoms in the block are held together by atomic bonding with the atoms in the string. Assuming the system in equilibrium in such a way that the tension arises to balance the weight of the blocks, and then the doubt begins: the atoms of the blocks that are attached to the atoms of the string under an electromagnetic force of the bond, as well as the atoms of the string each other. When the weight acts, this connection becomes a kind of "mini-string" between each atom, thus exerting a tension between the atoms of the block connected to the first atoms of the string, thus the second atoms of the string directly connected to the first atoms atoms of the string reflexively feel this tension as an attraction towards that second atom towards the atoms in the block, and the atoms in the blocks feel the same tension from them towards the atoms in the strings, as do the third atoms connected to the second also follow by this logic and so on to the other end. And this happens in exactly the same way as the other end of the string, but generating another tension opposite and equal in magnitude to the first case towards this other block, so that now the string has two tensions simultaneously in the same magnitude, direction and opposite, and a single tension affecting each block depending on the perspective of each block. My questions, in a somewhat realistic view of how string physics works, are as follows:

1. Is this tension a consequence of the "domino effect" of the action-reaction pairs from the first to the last atom of the string? (Considering that according to Newton's third law this domino effect, in fact, is one that happens simultaneously and instantaneously in all atoms)
2. Looking at the microscopic view, this tension force T that acts punctually on each block and extendably on the string is the sum of dT that exists in each atom added by the addition of blocks to the end of the string, or the T as a whole acts on each atom existing only the transfer of this end to end?
3. When tension occurs, does it occur as a separate component of the binding strength of the atoms, or does it directly affect the electromagnetic binding strength of the atoms so that, atomically speaking, there is a variation in the distance of the binding atom or atom? Because if the latter occurs, it's as if the "mini-string" formed by the atomic bond was somehow elastic, but if it causes a distancing of the atoms, the tension was subtracted in the bond implying the weakening of the bond and it does not make much sense for a tension to exist at the ends of the string as it was dissolved in the weakening of the bonds... but if that's not the case, if these bonds have no variation in the electromagnetic force due to the distance shifting of the atoms, then how does this tension come into being? Only by the action-reaction pair of the first atom to the atom, added to the still stable bond strength of the atoms, and thus generating a resultant force that still remains null in the string's internal system, but which generates an isolated tension at each end and the stability condition of this be limited until the case where the limit tension of the string will be reached and the atomic bond is instantly broken, consequently breaking the string?
4. This question may sound very layman, but it seems very strange to me that there are two equal and opposite forces on the same string that at the same time affect the objects at their ends and in parallel cancel each other in the string itself, being this condition of cancel a fact in the string since the string is not accelerated, so it is because it is in balance due to the balance of the two opposing tensions... however strangely for the blocks it is as if there is a certain relativity in this situation, as each block is only affected by a single tension, and this depends exclusively on the extreme that it finds connected, it is as if the position were an observation condition that interferes in which force will act on such block... make sense?
5. My teacher uses "traction" as the name of the force that appears on the rope when there is a suspended block, is that incorrect and the best pratice uses "tension"?